# inserting data from excel to sql table

Tags: c#, sql

Am getting an error while inserting data from excel to the database table.
this is the error **Incorrect syntax near 'NAME'**
this is my code:

```
 protected void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into MedicalItems (ITEM NAME,GROUP,ITEM TYPE,COST PRICE,SELLING PRICE,PURCHASE UOM,PURCHASE PACKAGING,DISPENSING UOM,QTY ON HAND,EXPIRY DATE,REORDER LEVEL,REORDER QUANTITY,BATCH#) values ('" + g1.Cells[0].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[1].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[3].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[4].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[5].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[6].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[7].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[8].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[9].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[10].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[11].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[12].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[13].Text + "')", con);

        con.Open();

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();



    }

    Label2.Text = "Records inserted successfully";

}
```

Comment: `ITEM NAME`. Either, there is a colon missing or it should be `[Item Name]`.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is also excited by this code. Use parameters!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the column names within [] like [ITEM NAME], for all the columns with whitespaces.